# Indexes that correspond to each other in two Lists

Tags: c#, list

I have two Lists:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
List<int> goals = new List<int>();
```

One of them is a string List while the other one is a int List. I add some numbers in the second List, and then I get the biggest number in the List. This works.

Now I need to type some names in the console and after each name I need to type a certain number and this repeats to whenever I want.

How do I get the index of the biggest number in the second list and to print it alongside the name that actually have "scored" that biggest number? I want to get the index from the first string List that corresponds to the index of the biggest number in the second List. Is there a way that I can do it?

Comment: Make it _one_ List of objects with two _properties_: Name and Goals.

Comment: Can you show me how if you have time I am still kinda newbie to be honest

Comment: 1) Create a class 2)Add Name property 3) Add goal property 4) Profit!  Post a proper programming question if you get stuck

Answer (score 1):

In your case, "Name" and "Goals" relate to each other. Someone or something with a "Name" has obviously attached to them a number of "Goals". So, let's reflect this relation in a class:

```
public class StatisticsItem
{
    // Properties here
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Goals {get; set;}
}
```

You then can create new *instances* of that class like so:

```
var item = new StatisticsItem() { Name = "Marc", Goals = 5 };
```

and you can put those in a list:

```
var myList = new List<StatisticsItem>();
myList.Add(item);
```

Find your champion:

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

Console.WriteLine("Goalie King: {0}", myList.MaxBy(x => x.Goals).Name);
```

See in action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/I9w5u7

---

To be a bit more clean, you could of course use a constructor:

```
public class StatisticsItem
{
    // Properties here
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Goals {get; set;}

    public StatisticsItem(string name, int goals)
    {
        Name = name;
        Goals = goals
    }
}

// and then create instances like so:
var item = new StatisticsItem("Marc", 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment so i will add my opinion here. Fildor suggested 1 list with 2 properties which should cover your case. I would say also check if a `dictionary<string, int>` or a `dictionary<string, List<int>>` is a better fit instead of a list.
Keep in mind for a dictionary to work the key (name in your case) must be unique. If not discard this answer